# Why does clr.AddReference fail on second IronPython engine?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, ironpython

When I try to add a reference to an IronPython engine instance, the reference get's added to the references as expected. If I create another instance of the engine, the AddReference executes without an error, but the reference is not added to the references and import statements fail with "no module named ...".

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic clr = engine.Runtime.GetClrModule();
clr.AddReference("IronPython.StdLib");
var references = (IEnumerable<Assembly>)clr.References;
Debug.Assert(references.Any(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronPython.StdLib"))); // ok

var source = "import pydoc\npydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(str))";
var result = engine.Execute<string>(source);
Debug.Assert(result.StartsWith("Python Library Documentation")); // ok

var engine2 = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic clr2 = engine2.Runtime.GetClrModule();
clr2.AddReference("IronPython.StdLib");
var references2 = (IEnumerable<Assembly>)clr.References;
Debug.Assert(references2.Any(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronPython.StdLib"))); // fails

result = engine.Execute<string>(source); // throws ImportException "no module named pydoc"
Debug.Assert(result.StartsWith("Python Library Documentation"));
```

I tried with the binary release of IronPython 2.7.5 (installed to GAC) and C# 4.5, `IronPython.StdLib` is a precompiled DLL of the Python standard lib with pyc.

I also tried with self compiled IronPython 2.7.5 and 2.7.6 from github, but there the first `engine.execute` already fails with `"no module named pydoc"` although the reference gets added.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague found out the reason for the failure. I post it here, in case someone else stumbles across this issue.

You need to load the assembly after adding the reference:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic clr = engine.Runtime.GetClrModule();
clr.AddReference("IronPython.StdLib");

// load assembly into engine
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("IronPython.StdLib.dll");
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(assembly); 

var references = (IEnumerable<Assembly>)clr.References;
Debug.Assert(references.Any(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronPython.StdLib"))); // ok

var source = "import pydoc\npydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(str))";
var result = engine.Execute<string>(source);
Debug.Assert(result.StartsWith("Python Library Documentation")); // ok

var engine2 = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic clr2 = engine2.Runtime.GetClrModule();
clr2.AddReference("IronPython.StdLib");

// load assembly into engine2
engine2.Runtime.LoadAssembly(assembly); 

var references2 = (IEnumerable<Assembly>)clr.References;
Debug.Assert(references2.Any(asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("IronPython.StdLib"))); // does not fail

result = engine.Execute<string>(source); // does not throw any more
Debug.Assert(result.StartsWith("Python Library Documentation"));
```